# day difference between today's date and a specified date in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How to find the day difference between today's date and a specified date in SQL. The specified date column(P.SubscrpEndDate__c) is in Date time format(12/1/2014 12:00 Am). I have used the below query but it do not works

```
DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(), P.SubscrpEndDate__c)  AS 'SubscriptionDueDate'
```

Comment: "it do not works" - in what way? It causes your computer to explode? You get an error message? You get a result unlike the one you expected? If it's the last of these, please give us an example of your actual inputs and what output you *expected* to get. If it's the error message, *what* does the error say?

Comment: I am writing a SQL query in Salesforce Marketing Cloud and trying to populate the data into the Data extension from Salescloud to Marketingcloud. Marketing cloud supports only few limited functions from SQL and hence functions like Now() do not works. If i am saying it do not works i mean to say that i am not getting data loaded into my data extension in Marketing cloud through the Query activity i am using.  In Marketing cloud it do not throws an error, if data is not getting populated it means it's not working.Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, [**`DATEDIFF`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function, takes only two arguments: end date and start date:

```
DATEDIFF(NOW(), P.SubscrpEndDate__c)  AS 'SubscriptionDueDate'
```

According to the manual:

> `DATEDIFF(expr1, expr2)` returns expr1 − expr2 expressed as a value in **days** from
>   one date to the other.

Also, to get the current date and time you have to use [**`NOW()`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) instead of `GETDATE`.

Answer (score 1):

It should work in SQL Server. I assume date column(SubscrpEndDate__c) in your table would contain lower values than current date, so simply you can use query below. I've just swapped second & third parameters to get positive difference in days. You can also use ABS() function to ignore negative difference.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,P.SubscrpEndDate__c,GETDATE() )  AS 'SubscriptionDueDate'
```

Comment: I used your query, there was no syntax error, however not getting the desired result. The data populated are P.SubscrpEndDate__c = 8/1/2016 12:00 AM and SubscriptionDueDate = 3/10/1900 12:00 AM. Seems DateDIFF function is not working. Any solution?

Comment: I hope you are using SQL Server. Below query works for me, I've just used date variables. Please add "@' prefixing variables.    DECLARE SubscrpEndDate__c DATETIME = '8/1/2016 12:00 AM' 
DECLARE SubscriptionDueDate DATETIME= '3/10/1900 12:00 AM'

SELECT DATEDIFF(dd,SubscriptionDueDate,SubscrpEndDate__c) AS DateDifference

Answer (score 0):

This would work, kindly check

SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(),P.SubscrpEndDate__c) AS SubscriptionDueDate FROM xyz_table WHERE id='123456'